# Get the country from city/state/etc human input

Tags: machine-learning, geocoding, sentiment-analysis, data-mapping, twitter

I have 200000 rows of twitter data having the location attribute. I want to map the city names to their respective countries for producing demographic result based on countries. How can I do that using some formula in excel or in other efficient way.
For example: **new delhi** mapped to **India**

[image: Data Sample: location attribute]

Comment: If accuracy is important to you, it will be impossible if you only have the city name. For example consider Paris, France vs. Paris, Texas. If you just have "Paris" as a location information, it will be impossible to say with certainty if the user is located in France or in the US. There are many cities sharing the same name.

Comment: Smriti, could you please post 10 sample rows?

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul, Following is the sample of data:

Tampa, Florida

St George, UT

Utah

Springfield OR

Hamilton, New Zealand

West Michigan

Haidian,Beijing,China

India

Comment: Thanks for the sample data, it is very valuable to know that the input data is not uniform and even contains some invalid entries.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to first geocode into latitude/longitude, then reverse geocode to get the country.

## Step 1: geocode

This step is the hardest as human-entered data can take many shapes. I would suggest this API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview

Be aware that it costs money.

Example when searching for `Springfield OR`:

[image]

A few alternative options are listed at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Geocoding

## Step 2: reverse geocode into a country

Good news, this one does not cost money and it is super-fast using this Java library coordinates2country:

https://github.com/coordinates2country/coordinates2country

Disclaimer: I made it, because I needed such a feature in one of my apps.

It includes a `run.sh` script runnable from Linux or Mac terminal. Example:

Enter `./run.sh 44.046236 -123.022029` on the terminal, press enter, this result gets displayed: `United States of America`